# How to specify xml file extension while serializing Xml to a GZipStream

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, xml-serialization, gzipstream

I am serializing an object with the following code, which uses GZip and Xml:

```
        FileStream fs = new FileStream(destinationfolder + "/myFileName.gz",
                                       FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
        using (var gz = new GZipStream(fs, CompressionMode.Compress)) {
            var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyObjectType));
            serializer.Serialize(gz, myObject);
        }
```

That works fine, with one single problem: The user can open the `.gz` file with 7Zip (after setting the file association), but then he can't just doubleclick the shown xml inside the `.gz` file, since it doesn't have the `.xml` extension (although the content is actually there, xml formatted and all).

Question is: "How can I serialize XML to a `GZipStream` so that the `.xml` extension is saved with the file, inside the `.gz` archive?" I'm using .NET 4.0.

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0):

I have figure out a simple way to solve that. If this way should be considered a hack or a pragmatic and fine solution, is up to each one, I think.

Simply set the GZip filename to `myFileName.xml.gz`. This actually makes the inner file appear as `myFileName.xml` (trimming out the `.gz` extension as before).

I hope this won't break in the future...